# Qt holds Ctrl to drag software elements into the File Explorer, but the File Explorer does not accept them

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I can receive when I don't press Ctrl, I need to implement Ctrl pressed for copy and Ctrl not pressed for cut (move), how can I achieve this?

Comment: What you mean system resource manager?   I know only clip borad

Comment: im sorry, system resource manager is File Explorer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, the `QDrag::exec()` function has some parameters to choose from, I rewrite it as `exec(Qt::ActionMask, Qt::MoveAction);` and it solves the problem perfectly.